# Using a null conditional offer to toggle display between none and block

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, razor

In my razor code , a specific div can only be displayed if a model has a value of more than 0 :

Razor View :

```
<div class="endorsedby" style="@(Model.user_skill_endorsed =   true ? "display:none" : "display:block")">
```

However when I attempt to this , it cannot find the values associated with this model :

Razor View:

```
@foreach (var skl in Model.user_skill_endorsed)
{
<a href="#"> @skl.user_forename @skl.user_surname  </a> <br />
}
```

I am aiming to toggle the visibility of my DIVs within MVC Razor and/or the controller without using any JavaScript (I have tried CSS3 active but unfortunately could not get this working.)

Thank you

Comment: Its unclear what you trying to do here. Your first code snippet is referring to `Model.user_skill_endorsed =  true`suggesting property `user_skill_endorsed` is a `boolean` value but the second code snippet suggests property `user_skill_endorsed` is a collection. How are these code blocks related? What are you actually trying to do? And show you model so its clear.

Comment: And do you mean _if a model has a **count** of more than 0_?

Comment: Yes I do mean if the model has a count of more than zero.

Comment: Then your condition would be `Model.user_skill_endorsed.Count() == 0` (or more simply `Model.user_skill_endorsed.Any()`). But why do you need this. If there are no items, none of the links will be rendered and you will just have a empty `<div>` which wont be visible

Comment: The aim is so the user can click on a link and a div element will appear. so if a user clicks on a specific skill_id , a div element would appear. I don't wish to use Javascript.

Comment: You cannot do that without using javascript. Your div element is either visible or not visible when the page is first displayed. If you want to change that state based on clicking on another element, then you need javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi there Can you try this without the = true?

<div class="endorsedby" style="@(Model.user_skill_endorsed ? "display:none" : "display:block")">
```

You can always write out the value of @(Model.user_skill_endorsed) to see if your actually getting a value from it (or correct value).

Then you can focus on fixing the logic since the value is actually there.